# type 'Query' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot>?'

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, syntax-error, snapshot

in Flutter, I have collection called vendors and I am going to get collection base on the image of its collection

here is my code:

```
class _TopPickStoreState extends State<TopPickStore>{
StoreService _storeServices = StoreService();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
   return Container(
   child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
     stream: _storeServices.getTopPickedStore(),
     builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapShot){
      if(!snapShot.hasData)return CircularProgressIndicator();
      return Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: snapShot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document){
                  return Container(
                    width: 80,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Image.network(document['imageUrl']),
                      ]
                    ),
                  )
                ;}).toList(),
              ),
          )
        ],
      );
    }
    ),
);
```

}
}

this is the function to get the collection:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


 class StoreService{
     getTopPickedStore(){
       return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vendors')
       .where('accVerified', isEqualTo:true)
       .where('isTopPicked',isEqualTo: true)
       .orderBy('shopName');
     }
   }
```

and i got this error message:

type 'Query' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot ?'

can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: The problem is being caused by `getTopPickedStore()`, post this function. Because it's returning `query` object, but your streambuilder is querysnapshot. Decide which one of them you want to use, then it can be fixed

Comment: i have put the getTopPickedStore() function, i hope you can explain more to me how to solve the problem. thank you very much

Comment: I added an answer. Basically what's written currently in the function is a query. Meaning it's a set of instructions to tell Firebase where and what to look for, but you don't tell it what to do afterwards. It has to be told to `get()` or `snapshots()`, to actually go to firebase, and get those documents, and then return them as a querysnapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
getTopPickedStore() async {
       return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vendors')
       .where('accVerified', isEqualTo:true)
       .where('isTopPicked',isEqualTo: true)
       .orderBy('shopName').snapshots();
```

You need to use snapshots to change it into a querysnapshot.